# Effective mass definition

Tags: condensed-matter, mass, solid-state-physics, definition

Given an energy spectrum $\epsilon_k$, there are two common definitions of the effective mass $m^*$:

1. $$\frac{1}{m^*}=\frac{\partial^2\epsilon_k}{\partial k^2},$$
2. $$\frac{1}{m^*}=\frac{v_F}{k_F},$$

where $v_F$ and $k_F$ are the Fermi velocity and Fermi momentum, respectively. In general, the two definitions are not equivalent.

How are the two definitions related, both physically and mathematically?

Comment: As this depends on conventions, can you please be more explicit about how $v_F,k_F$ are defined (and perhaps, include a reference for your two possible definitions of $m^*$)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, it is useful to *correct your definitions* so that $k$ is the usual wave vector in $k$-space:

1. $$\frac{1}{m^*}=\frac{1}{\hbar^2}\frac{\partial^2\epsilon_k}{\partial k^2},$$
2. $$\frac{1}{m^*}=\frac{1}{\hbar}\frac{v_F}{k_F},$$

(1) The first definition is the effective mass definition at any chosen point in $k$-space for a *general* spherically symmetric $\epsilon_k (k)$ dispersion relationship  .

(2) The second definition is the same effective mass definition as in 1., also for a spherically symmetric dispersion relation,  taken at the Fermi energy in $k$-space with a *parabolic* dispersion relationship $$\epsilon_k (k)= \frac {\hbar^2 k^2}{2 m^*}$$ with $$v_F=\frac {1}{\hbar}\frac{\partial {\epsilon_k}}{{\partial k}}|_{k=k_F}=\frac {\hbar k_F}{m^*}$$ where $k_F=k(\epsilon_F)$.

Thus the second definition follows from the first only for a parabolic dispersion relation when the location in $k$-space where the effective mass is calculated is at the Fermi energy.

Comment: Yes, useful for many. But for some people, $\hbar=1$.